# IIS using machine name for SQL Server authentication

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

After moving my MVC 4 applicaiton on production the IIS is using

```
domain/machinename$
```

to access the SQL database on a different server. The SQL server is configured to accept connection from

```
mydomain/myuser
```

I'm wondering how to fix this and make it pass the correct credentials, in my connection string I have

```
Integrated Security=SSPI
```

and I deployed as my user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIS is using the identity of the Application Pool to login to SQL server because you have the Intergrated Security setting.  Change the identity of your application pool to run as the Domain/User or specify the login credentials in the connection string to SQL.

SQL Connection String with specified credentials

```
Server=myServerName\myInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;
```

Comment: right now its using DefaultAppPool, and the Identity is set to ApplicationPoolIdentity. I have the option to change it to Network service, LocalSystem or LocalService. I have tried all of them still no success. There is also another field "Load User Profile" it is set to false by default so I set it to true but still nothing. How can I make it run as Domain/User?

Comment: In IIS (assuming 7.0 and higher), go to Application Pools, right click the AppPool that you want to change and choose Advanced Settings.  Find Identity under Process Model, click the triple ellipse. Choose custom account, set the information.  Then restart the app pool

Comment: I tried so many other threads last night and came in today, found this post, and your simple explanation fixed it for me.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I used Custom account for the identity and it worked